# How do I get an XML file from the assets folder using a function?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, parsing

How do I get an XML file from the assets folder using a function and save the result of the function to a String variable?

Comment: What did you try and what is the specific problem?

Comment: what your app problem?

Comment: I tried to use androidhive;s example of parsing an xml file from an address. However, I would need to parse an xml file that is just located under my assets folder. You can refer to this link. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private String getXmlFile(String pathFile){

  String xmlFileString = null;
  AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
  try {
    InputStream str = am.open(pathFile);
    int length = str.available();
    byte[] data = new byte[length];
   //str.what you want somthing to do...eg read and write str.read(data); and   st.write(data);
    xmlFileString = new String(data);
      } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     }

   return xmlFileString;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider this AssetManager(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Help Full For u

AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();

InputStream is = assetManager.open("order.xml");

[Xml Parsing From Asset in Android](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-parse-xml-file-from-assets-or.html)